# Problems with setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a problem, again jajaja.

```
var X=0
var Y=0
```

With this function, i want to add Y to X every second.

```
function FA(){
    X= X+Y;
    setTimeout(function(){FA()},1000); 
}
```

With this funcion, i want to add 1 to Y.

```
function FB()
{
    Y=Y+1;   
}
```

Example:

```
Y=0
X=0
X=0
X=0
[...]
(execute the function FB) 
Y=1
X=1
X=2
X=3
[...]
```

My problem is that the second time that i execute FB its not +2 to X, its +4 and i want only +2.

Comment: I don't get it jajaja

Comment: seems that you may fire FA second time with FB maybe...

Comment: Your code is fine. I just did a quick test and it works just fine. On one call of FB, y===1, then x is incremented by 1. On another call, y === 2, then x is incremented by 2.

Comment: Can you recrete the problem in a fiddle? work fine here : http://jsfiddle.net/WLEuz/

Comment: @GôTô it's how Spanish speakers would express laughter (hahaha)

Comment: @TomFenech Thanks Tom! I didn't know. My comment was also related to the question, a bit unclear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks ok. I'd change some syntax details to make it simpler:

```
function FA(){
    X += Y;
    setTimeout("FA()",1000); 
}

function FB(){
    Y++;
}
```

i think the problem may be somewhere in the code you didn't post. it looks like you add Y value twice, so tripple-check if you call FA again. It would cause what you are experiencing now (you may have TWO timeouts).

Comment: thank you very much, the problem was another time out :p

Comment: @GDP glad i could help. please click the accept button (under voting arrows)